# Load data from Firebase Firestore to array - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying get data from firestore. Connection is ok, data is downloading but with problems.

I'm based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data example.

```
let list = [];

let products = function GetCollection() {
    firestore.collection("products")
        .get()
        .then(function (querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                list.push(doc.data());
            });
            $scope.collection = list;
        });
}
products();

console.log("test");
```

After run this code, my list is empty but in console are listed all entries. During debuging i noticed that last line with console.log("test") is executed before all body of GetCollection() function.
This is problem with sync? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

yes this is expected behavior, `console.log("test");` will be executed first. Because part `.then(function (querySnapshot` is a asynchronous  call, what you are passing inside `.then`  is a javascript promise, and that is asynchronous

you should also use handle error as mentioned in below line 
`.get(some comde). then ( function -- ). catch ( function (error) {  console.log("Error getting cached document:", error); } )`

for testing purpose, you can use firebase synchronous version of method as well, generally firebase api have corresponding sync version of method, and if I remember correctly  those are suffixed with "sync"